# VBA: Set variable as worksheet on open for use throughout other modules and forms

Tags: excel, vba, variables, public, worksheet

I want to set a Public (global) variable when the workbook opens. I want this variable to be set as a worksheet so I can use that variable throughout my workbook to call up that sheet. I want to do this so that if someone changes a sheet name, I can simply change the sheet name in one location.

ThisWorkbook: I have added a Public variable and set it as a worksheet. In Workbook_Open() I have then: Set variable = Sheets("config_page"). In module1, I then have code that tries to use variable like this: variable.activate or variable.select or variable.cells(LastRow, 1).

In ThisWorkbook> Auto_Open, I have already tried to set the variable as a string and made global_variable = Sheets("config_page").Name. Then in the form, I have variable as worksheet and Set global_variable = Sheets(variable). The forms doesn't load.

ThisWorkbook:

Public global_variable as worksheet

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Set global_variable = Sheets("config_page")

End Sub

Module1:

Sub open_form()

frm_Form.show

End Sub
```

frm_Form:

```
UserForm.Initialize()

global_variable.active

End Sub
```

I want to be able to use a variable that is a worksheet so that I can access it from forms and modules throughout the workbook.

Comment: If you set the worksheet's *codeName* (in the VB editor) you can refer to that directly without having to worry about users changing the name on the worksheet tab.

Comment: Been a while since I have been in VBA. You nailed it. Good stuff.